# DynamoDB - query based on multiple columns

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement to find all users in a table that have same Id, Email or Phone.

Right now the data looks like this:

```
Id //hash

Market //sort

Email //gsi

Phone //gsi
```

I want to be able to do a query and say:

Get all items that have matching Id, email or phone.

From the docs it seems that you can only do a single query based on keys or one index. And it seems that even if I was to combine phone and email into one column and GSI that column I would still be limited to a begin with filter expression, is this correct? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

> it seems that you can only do a single query based on keys or one index

Yes.

> if I was to combine phone and email into one [GSI] I would still be limited to a begin with filter expression, is this correct?

Essentially, yes.  Query constraints apply equally to indexes and the table keys.  You must specify *one-and-only-one* `Partition Key` value, and optionally a [range of](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions)  `Sort Key` values.

> Are there any alternatives?

Overload the `Partition Key` and [denormalise](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/should-your-dynamodb-table-be-normalized-or-denormalized/) the data.   Redefine the `Partition Key` column (renamed `PK`) to hold `Id`, `Email` and `Phone` values.  Each record is  (fully or partially) repeated 3 times, each time with a different `PK` type.

```sh
PK              Market          Id       More fields        
Id-1            A               Id-1     foo
zaphod@42.com   A               Id-1     # foo or blank
13015552572     A               Id-1     # foo or blank
```

Querying `PK = <something> AND Market > ""` will return any matching id, email or phone number value.

If justified by your query patterns, repeat all fields 3x.  Alternatively, use a hit on a truncated email/phone record to identify the `Id`, then query other fields using the `Id`.

There are different flavours of this pattern.  For instance, you could also overload the `Sort Key` column (renamed to `SK`) with the `Id` value for `Email` and `Phone` records, which would permit multiple `Id`s per email/phone.